# In math mode, when is it appropriate to use ~ as opposed to \,?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, best-practices, semantics

In math mode, a whitespace may be inserted using either a tilde (`~`) or a comma command (`\,`).

E.g.:

```
W=\{x,y~|~x+y=3\}
% or
W=\{x,y\,|\,x+y=3\}
```

Are either of these frowned upon in general? Is it largely just a stylistic difference? When should I use a tilde as opposed to a comma command?

Comment: Use semantic / symbolic commands. Isn't `W = \{ x, y \given x + y = 3 \}` better? Or may be with little more effort you have a bit more power `W = \set{ x, y \given x + y = 3 }`. Then you can define `\given` in any way you want (this doesn't answer this specific question, but I think it's a good way to go).

Comment: I hadn't thought of creating a `\given` macro, thanks! It helps in this specific case, but I'm interested in a general-case answer; white space exists outside of set notation, after all.

Comment: See the mathtools manual for a set defining macro that uses the idea of `\given`, hint it has build in scaling abilities.

Comment: Also space in math is a very special discussion and is very different than outside math. I'd never use `~` in math mode.

Comment: @daleif does that mean you _would_ use `\,`, or that you'd avoid using whitespace in general?

Comment: Depends on context. In some cases, for example in `\given` I use `\:`, in may others I use `\quad` and `\qquad` when more visual space are needed. Even then I apply rules on to when I use what. It is rare I explicitly use `\, ` it depends on the math expression

Comment: Honestly, you'll probably get three different opinions when you ask two separate people. And their opinions may change over time. I've cast a vote-to-close as this may post may solicit primarily opinion-based answers.

Comment: Here's my two cent: `W = \{\, (x,y) \mid x+y=3 \,\}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the TeXbook, Knuth advocates writing neither `\,|\,` nor `~|~` for the expression at hand. Given that (pun intended) the `|` symbol would be read out loud as "given that", it is a relational operator (in TeX jargon) and should therefore be surrounded by "thickspace". (Other objects of mode "mathrel" are `=`, `<`, and `>`.) PlainTeX and LaTeX both provide the macro `\mid` to meet this particular typesetting purpose.

In fact, the TeXbook would recommend writing your equation as

```
W=\{ \, x,y \mid x+y=3 \, \}
```

Observe the thinspace directives *inside* the opening and closing curly braces -- in addition to `\mid`.